# Floating point powers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in javascript, using 3JS library. I am not supposed to reveal the question or the code, so I will come straight to the problem I am facing.

I have to use a code to evaluate the following expression, for a purpose -

y = 0.2*(x<sup>0.926</sup>)+0

The problem I am facing here is that if I try to evaluate x<sup>0.926</sup> using `Math.pow(x,0.926)` I get **NaN** as a result.

I cannot use `y = 0.2*x` directly, because it makes a huge difference to the appearance.

Could anyone give me an alternate code for this?

Comment: So what is `x` that it is producing NaN?

Comment: Just tested, that expression works fine. What's the value of x? Is it an unparsed string?

Comment: x must be a string, or null, or undefined -  instead of a number, for a NaN

Comment: @Luicy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents

Comment: Hm, very well. That's my bad, I was thinking of something completely different. I'll remove my comments.

Comment: @developer thanks for guiding me in the right direction that the fault may be due to the value of x, than fractional exponent. I just realized that x had a negative value, and hence probably no fractional exponent is evaluated, though it may have a valid answer. But trust me, it worked in my scientific calculator. Anyways thanks.